# "ConcurrentModificationException" when updating my entities

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, jpa

### Problem

Im using hibernate 5.4.11 core and when i try to update large amounts of entities i run into that issue right here. It looks like an hibernate internal exception.

### Update

I tested it with hibernate 5.4.23, the same exception occured.
I also updated my "mysql connector" to the latest version "8.0.22" and it didnt worked either, the same exception.

### Describtion

This is how i update my entities, it runs in another thread, which should not be the problem here... its basically a own thread for database operations, during that operation no other database operations are running.

```java
        // Run the database operation for updating the entities async in a new thread, return updated entities once done
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {

            var session = database.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            try {

                // Save identities first
                for (var identity : identities)
                    session.update(identity);

                // Update components, each component-type
                for(var insertedClass : insertationOrder)
                    for (var hbc : componentsPerType.get(insertedClass))
                        session.update(hbc);

                session.flush();
                session.clear();

                session.getTransaction().commit();
            } catch (Exception e){

                var messageComposer = new ExceptionMessageComposer(e);
                GameExtension.getInstance().trace("Update : "+messageComposer.toString());
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
            }

            session.close();
        }).thenApply(v -> entities);
```

The class i try to save

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "chunk", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"x", "y"})}, indexes = {@Index(columnList = "x,y")})
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
@SelectBeforeUpdate(false)
public class Chunk extends HibernateComponent{

    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Date createdOn;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "chunk_identity", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "identity_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"), inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @BatchSize(size = 50)
    public Set<Identity> inChunk = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @Transient
    public Set<ChunkLoader> loadedBy = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public Chunk() {}
    public Chunk(int x, int y, Date createdOn) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "location")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Transform extends HibernateComponent {

    @Embedded
    public Vector2 position = new Vector2();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "chunk_id", referencedColumnName = "identity_id", updatable = false)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    public Chunk chunk;

    @Transient
    public Vector2 previousPos = new Vector2();

    public Transform() {}
    public Transform(Vector2 position) { this.position = position; }
    public Transform(Vector2 position, Chunk chunk) { this.position = position; this.chunk = chunk; }
}
```

The exception i get

```java
19:29:05,126 INFO  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19] Extensions     - {Game}: Update : java.util.ConcurrentModificationException:
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
Message: *** Null ***
+--- --- ---+
Stack Trace:
+--- --- ---+
java.base/java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1493)
java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1516)
org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.insertRows(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1555)
org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionUpdateAction.execute(CollectionUpdateAction.java:89)
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1356)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1343)
com.parallelorigin.persistence.database.ECSDatabase.lambda$updateEntities$16(ECSDatabase.java:242)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1728)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Anyone having an idea why hibernate throws that internal exception and what i could do to solve this issue ?

Comment: are you modifying those entities in main thread while it is being persisted ?

Comment: @SKumar Well thats true, i modify both of them each frame, even while its being saved. Is this a problem ? The list in chunk also gets modified on a regulary base... it would make sense that this is the reason... but whats an alternative ? I cant simply pause the game :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't change the list of `entities`, `identities` or `components` that you persist/update while another thread is working on it.

The thread that persists/updates entities must **own** the entity objects i.e. no other thread may interfere with the state while the transaction is running. You can only make use of the objects again after the transaction finished.

I don't know what your application does, but if you need access to the objects in your main thread you could copy the objects for the flush operation. This way, the thread doing the flush will properly own the objects and can safely work on them.

Comment: Hey, i have another little question here ^^ First of all, thanks for your help ! Im now "copying" the entities... but that brings me to another issue... one of my copied entities contains a list, when i update that entity it inserts all its childs to the database... and it does that every single time, it does not update its childs, it inserts them and that throws an "Duplicate entry" exception :/ Any idea what i could do in this case ?

Comment: Whether an object is inserted or updated depends on the identifier and identifier strategy that you use. I guess you are using a generated identity? If so, make sure the identifier is properly set. Can you maybe use a `Set` instead of a `List`? Maybe you really have duplicate objects.

Comment: Thanks ! No im not using generated identites, i set them by myself :) The child identities are set correctly. How does hibernate know when it should insert, update or remove a child ? Thats my current database flow : 1. Deep clone Entities 2. session.update them 3. Repeat Step 1 after a few minutes. It works the first time and the childs are getting inserted, the second time however, the childs are inserted again which results in that exception... still no clue why

Comment: I'd need to see the entity definitions, but I suspect that Hibernate can't access the id properly or maybe you mapped the table multiple times and Hibernate tries to do the insert for a many to many association.